# Angular directive handling of data using $parse and with bindings in the template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

A plunker for this question is at http://plnkr.co/edit/CfIryhwmlpme1ZSfnEom?p=preview

I need help with various issues here:

1. The first is that the plunker isn't exactly working as I expect...why?  It should print the types of the data used in the directive attributes.
2. In my real app, I can't seem to get the use of the $parse service in directives.  I've tried various approaches and can't get the thing to work.  Simple attributes work ok in the real app.
3. I think the directive template is ok as coded but if not please like to hear your comments.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at the browser console: "Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined"?

Comment: simpleType and objectType are not directives. I don't think it can be access that way. And I don't think `directive` supports the way you're writing it.

Comment: My bad...that's what happens when you rush things :-)  I've cleaned up the plunker but still I fail to understand why it is not generating the directive template.  Maybe I'm not using Plunker correctly.  If someone can demonstrate the use of $parse in a directive that takes a obj.model defined in the MainCtrl and displays its value the directive's template that would be sufficient for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/8PdUObsw7FB3xbrEaqto?p=preview)

I have changed your watch expression

```
scope.$watch('item', function(item) {
          inventoryUpdates++;
          console.log("inventory status["+inventoryUpdates+"]==>item="+item);
          scope.itemName = item.rack1.name;
          scope.itemCount = item.rack1.count;
        },true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Should it look Like this?

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IKIHb6Z9s2hock1gF5pT?p=preview)

regards

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Can someone please make the $watch in the showInventory directive of the following plunker work: http://plnkr.co/edit/yzJvA30SevBGwPVJ8mrL?p=preview

I'm not too sure how to set it up to watch for the updates to the inventory and then show the latest inventory per the directive template.  Thanks!